# Where has computedFrom gone

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm using the latest aurelia-validation packages, I have noted that I cannot locate the computedFrom. Has this been replaced or completely removed?

Example:

```
            .ensure('Sku1', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['Sku2', ‘Sku1'])})
            .if(() => { return !this.HasProvidedEitherSku })
                .isNotEmpty().withMessage('a SKU is required')
                .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
            .endIf()
            .ensure('Sku2', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['Sku2', 'Sku1'])})
            .if(() => { return !this.HasProvidedEitherSku })
                .isNotEmpty().withMessage('a SKU is required')
                .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
            .endIf();
```

Method

```
@computedFrom('Sku1', 'Sku2')
get HasProvidedEitherSku(){
    if (this.Sku1 === '' && this.Sku2 === '')){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is the config.computedFrom.

*UPDATE*

If equality replaces computedFrom, would I do something like this:

```
constraints = {
  complexAttribute: {
    equality: {
      message: "a SKU is require",
      comparator: function(v1, v2) {
        return this.Sku1 !== '' || this.Sku2 !== '';
      }
    }
  }
};
```

How do I assign that to SKU1/SKU2?

Answer (score 0):

`computedFrom` that was part of `aurelia-validation` no longer exists.  The new `aurelia-validation` is a complete rewrite.  Many patterns/ideas such as the fluent API and decorators are still around but none of the original code remains.

Comment: what is the alternative to computedFrom?

Comment: depends- what were you using `computedFrom` for?  `aurelia-binding` has a `computedFrom` already.

Comment: Is there an analog of the `computedFrom` validation function in the reworked library?

Comment: It's called equality I believe and comes from validatejs.  Documentation should reflect this although perhaps might not be as clear